# Stop carriage return from appearing in stringstream

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

I'm have some text parsing that I'd like to behave identically whether read from a file or from a stringstream. As such, I'm trying to use an `std::istream` to perform all the work. In the string version, I'm trying to get it to read from a static memory byte array I've created (which was originally from a text file). Let's say the original file looked like this:

```
4
```

The corresponding byte array is this:

```
const char byte_array[] = { 52, 13, 10 };
```

Where 52 is ASCII for the character 4, then the carriage return, then the linefeed.

When I read directly from the file, the parsing works fine.

When I try to read it in "string mode" like this:

```
std::istringstream iss(byte_array);
std::istream& is = iss;
```

I end up getting the carriage returns stuck on the end of the strings I retrieve from the stringstream with this method:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(is, line);
```

This screws up my parsing because the `string.empty()` method no longer gets triggered on "blank" lines -- every line contains at least a `13` for the carriage return even if it's empty in the original file that generated the binary data.

Why is the `ifstream` behaving differently from the `istringstream` in this respect? How can I have the `istringstream` version discard the carriage return just like the `ifstream` version does?

Comment: My guess is that the `ifstream` removes the CR characters when the file is opened in text mode, but `istringstream` has no concept of "text mode" and so always operates effectively in binary mode.  (Try opening the file with mode `ios_base::binary` and see if the problem then occurs with the file.)  The solution, I think, would be to remove the "13" element from `byte_array`.

Comment: That's one thing I've considered -- removing the CR from my binary generation. That's a good backup solution that'd require some work but would likely cure the symptom. It seems a bit bizarre to me that an istringstream would *not* operate in "text mode"! It's for strings!

Comment: @aardvarkk: `text mode` is only relevant for file streams. When you read and write from a file the line endings are always translated for you, so in the code you should only have to deal with `\n`. With stringstreams, it should be the same.

Comment: @aardvarkk Strings in C++ are sequences of things, not necessarily characters of text. `std::string` for example is a sequence of bytes -- how those bytes are interpreted is up to the consumer of the class.  `istringstream` does not do any interpretation or special processing.  In this case, that interpretation/processing should happen at the time you read the file, which is *before* the code is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ifstream` operates in text mode by default, which means it will convert non-LF line endings to a single LF.  In this case, `std::ifstream` is removing the CR character before `std::getline()` ever sees it.

`std::istringstream` does not do any interpretation of the source string, and passes through all bytes as they are in the string.

It's important to note that `std::string` represents a sequence of *bytes*, not characters.  Typically one uses `std::string` to store ASCII-encoded text, but they can also be used to store arbitrary binary data.  The assumption is that if you have read text from a file into memory, you have already done any text transformations such as standardization of line endings.

The correct course of action here would be to convert line endings when the file is being read.  In this case, it looks like you are generating code from a file.  The program that reads the file and converts it to code should be eliminating the CR characters.

An alternative approach would be to write a stream wrapper that takes an `std::istream` and delegates read operations to it, converting line endings on the fly.  This approach is viable, though can be tricky to get right.  (Efficiently handling seeking, in particular, will be difficult.)

Comment: My solution was in the vein of your recommendation. Since I had control over the writing process of the binary data, I simply stopped it from writing the carriage returns on the output side. No checks were required on the input side afterward.